# replace every second value in a sequence with special character '*'

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Let's take Input from user as `9`. So the Fibonacci series upto 9 is as follow's   `0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21`

**Expected Output :** `0,*,1,*,3,*,8,*,21`

**Below is the following code which i work around to implement logic**

```
UserInput=9 
a=0 
b=1 

echo "The Fibonacci series is  : "

for (( i=0; i<UserInput; i++ )) 
do
    if [ $i -eq 2 ]
    then 
        echo -n "$a "
        sn=$((a + b)) 
        a=$b 
        b=$sn 
    fi 
done
```

Comment: Pleased share the shell script you have developed so far and indicate the point you are stuck.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli  code is shared have a look at it

Comment: Where you say every consecutive number. Did you mean every other field? You example does not show the `*`s on the consecutive numbers.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor   every consecutive means every 2nd number of series should be mask with special character '*'  , please see the Expected output : `0,*,1,*,3,*,8,*,21`

Comment: I did see the example, that is why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandatory `awk`-based solution (where for simplicity I will assume `n>2`):

```
awk -v n=9 'BEGIN{q=1; printf "0,*,"; for (i=2;i<n;i++) {s=q+r;r=q;q=s; printf "%s%s",i%2?"*":s,i==n-1?"\n":","}}'
```

The user input is stored in the variable `n` and passed to `awk` via the command-line argument `-v n=number`.

In order to exit immediately if `n<3`:

```
awk -v n=9 'BEGIN{if (n<3) exit; q=1; printf "0,*,"; for (i=2;i<n;i++) {s=q+r;r=q;q=s; printf "%s%s",i%2?"*":s,i==n-1?"\n":","}}'
```

**Explanation**

`awk` is a text-processing tool, we are "creatively misusing" it. Therefore, everything happens inside the `BEGIN` block which usually contains code executed before the first input file is processed.

The syntax itself is very C-like, so we

- print the first two terms of the series (which are fixed since we assume `n>2`): `printf "0,*,"`
- loop from `2` to `n-1` and calculate the Fibonaccy number `s` as sum of the two previous ones `q` and `r`, and update `q` and `r`
- print either `*` if `i` is even, or the current Fibonacci number `s` if it is not (`i%2?"*":s`)
- and print either a `,` or a newline after that, depending on whether we have reached the end of the loop (`i==n-1`) or not.

Comment: i seen most of the answers from you is in awk is their any special about awk. May be i required to brush up with awk basic and internally working .. i need to always ask you for detail explanation

Answer (score 2):

The closest to your code, using Bash and arithmetic operators is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
let UserInput=9 
let a=0 
let b=1
echo -n "The Fibonacci series is: 0"
for (( i=1; i<UserInput; i++ )) ; do
  let sn=a+b
  let a=b
  let b=sn
  if (( i % 2 == 0 )) ; then 
    echo -n ",$a"
  else
    echo -n ",*"
  fi 
done
echo
```

In the `if` statement you have to use the `%` modulo (remainder) operator. Using it you can test whether `i` is divisible to two (i.e. an even number) and print the value of `$a` or print a `*` accordingly.

The output will be:

```
The Fibonacci series is: 0,*,1,*,3,*,8,*,21
```

To change the script, so that it gets the number of steps from its *argument*, please modify the first line of the script like this:

```
let UserInput="$1"
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution , I was trying to store it into array and replace with sed command